# Tailwind CLI stopped picking up new classes

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am using this command to continually build my output.css file.
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

This has been working but for some reason it suddently stopped in a weird way. Meaning, adding any new classes to my input.css file doesn't change the output.css. Like, the lines below are not being generated in the output.css.

```
.this-is-test {
  @apply tw-text-ellipsis;
}
```

I have tried to figure out what is the exact problem and the strange thing is:

1. Adding new styles blocks to id selectors works fine.

```
#this-is-test {
  @apply tw-text-ellipsis;
}
```

2. Adding new tailwind style classes to an existing class, let's say to `.exisitng-class` works fine.